# 2003 Toyota 4 runner blower works intermittently

Tags: toyota, 4runner, heater-blower

2003 v6 Toyota 4 runner
I have replaced the relay and checked the resistor blower fan looks good,
what else can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! At this point would either boil down to the switch or the wiring. At least that'd be my best guess.

Comment: You need to diagnose the problem.  It could be the speed control (often that's the problem), the motor itself, the load resistor, the wiring, or the connectors.